# JCC installation: Java JDK dictionary does not exist

Tags: lucene, pylucene, jcc

I have installed the source code for PyLucene which contains the JCC source code. When trying to run `python setup.py build` in the JCC directory I receive the following error:

`Java JDK directory 'c:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.6.0_18' does not exist.`

`Please set the environment variable JCC_JDK to the correct location before
running setup.py.`

Could someone help me with setting up the correct environment variable?

Answer (score 0):

If you're running windows, go to system environment variables:
right click on "This PC" -> properties -> Advanced system settings -> make sure you are on "Advanced" tab and click on "Environment Variables...":

[image]

Then, in the System variables window select "new..." and enter JCC_JDK as Variable name and the path to your jdk as the Variable value.